# Mongoose calculate average

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got the following mongoose models:

```
var MobileAppSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    identifier: String,
    ...
});

var RecordingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ... ,
  app: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'MobileApp'
  },
  length: Number,
  ...
});
```

Now I get some records of MobileAppSchema and I want to get all RecordingSchemas where Recording.app equals one of my MobileApps. For all the fetched documents I want to get the average of Recording.length.

My current approach works, however I want to aggregate directly with mongoose queries and not afterwards.

Current implementation:

```
exports.averageTimeSpentForAppIdentifier = function(appIdentifier, done) {
    mobileAppsForAppIdentifier(appIdentifier, function(err, mobileApps) {
        if(err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        var appIds = mobileApps.map(function(mobileApp) {return mobileApp._id;});

        Recording.find({
            'app': { $in: appIds}}, function(err, recordings) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if(!recordings || recordings.length == 0) {
                return done(null, 0);
            }

            var average = recordings
            .map(function(recording,i,arr) {
                return recording.length/arr.length
            })
            .reduce(function(a,b) {
                return a + b
            });

            done(null, average);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: And your problem is? Because even a naive search turns up quite a handsome number of results that explain how to calculate aggregates in mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation framework is at your disposal here. Running the following pipeline will give you the desired result. It uses the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline as the initial step to filter out documents getting into the aggregation
pipeline which do not make the given criteria of mobileApps ids.

The **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator which follows is for the main aggregation i.e. calculating the average length of the grouped documents using the **[`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg)** accumulator operator:

```
exports.averageTimeSpentForAppIdentifier = function(appIdentifier, done) {
    mobileAppsForAppIdentifier(appIdentifier, function(err, mobileApps) {
        if(err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        var appIds = mobileApps.map(function(mobileApp) {return mobileApp._id;}),
            pipeline = [
                {"$match": { "app": { $in: appIds } } },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": null,
                        "average": { "$avg": "$length" }
                    }
                }
            ];

        Recording.aggregate(pipeline)
                .exec(function (err, result){
                    if(err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    done(null, result[0].average);
                })

        // Or using the fluent pipeline builder API         
        Recording.aggregate()
                .match({ "app": { $in: appIds } })
                .group({ "_id": null, "average": { "$avg": "$length" }})
                .exec(function (err, result){
                    if(err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    done(null, result[0].average);
                });       
    });
};
```